# Edit page.php , include external stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a link tag I added in the page.php it worked . 
Now I want to use my own stylesheet I tried the folowing but is did not work out :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('iww/cms/css/description1.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<div><a  class="atlwdg-trigger atlwdg-RIGHT" href="#">Feedback?</a></div>
```

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

you can only use the options available in the bloginfo() function
see here.. [wordpress bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

try something like this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('url').'iww/cms/css/description1.css'; ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<div><a  class="atlwdg-trigger atlwdg-RIGHT" href="#">Feedback?</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the bloginfo function on the [Wordpress bloginfo page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo). Use `<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/the/rest/of/your/path.css`

So in your `header.php` replace this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('iww/cms/css/description1.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<div><a  class="atlwdg-trigger atlwdg-RIGHT" href="#">Feedback?</a></div>
```

With this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/iww/cms/css/description1.css" type="text/css" media="screen"
```

**EDIT:**

```
'stylesheet_directory' displays the stylesheet directory URL of the active theme.
```

So please check your url. You can easily check it if you go to your website and look at your source code. There is your `<link rel="" href="" type="" media="" />` tag. If the link is correct, check if you maybe edit another file which is named the same. If the path is wrong, correct it in your `header.php`

**EDIT 2:**

I updated the `<link>` tag. As you can see I removed the `echo`. An `echo` is not needed there, it should work without `echo` (for me, it works perfect).

Comment: Hello , 
Thanks for the reply but I have no idea why calling the css is not working .

Comment: For me this always works fine. Maybe your path is wrong? Check if `<?php get_header(); ?>` is in your page.php file. Also the `get_footer()`

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>   and <?php get_header(); ?> are available , I changed the location of my css file to same folder with the page.php , small question what did you mean by (stylesheet_directory) does it mean the whole path ,? now I do not have a path what shall I out ?

Comment: `'stylesheet_directory'` is a link to your active theme (the folder where header.php, index.php etc. are in). With `/iww/cms/css/description1.css` you can link to a specific file (in this case, your `description1.css` file. Have you noticed my edits?

Answer (score 0):

edit **header.php** insted of **page.php** in your template directory and add following code just before close of head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('url').'iww/cms/css/description1.css'; ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: please clarify , edit header.php, do you mean I should include the css call there ?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to include css file in the header section so open the header.php file and add this line to include the css file

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If your css file path is iww/cms/css/description1.css so include this line

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/iww/cms/css/description1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: In wordpress it will definitely work.Something is wrong in your code

Comment: In page.php page include this line if you not include get_header(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

This code also useful, try it. It will also work.

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Hope the answer helps!